# c# p2p library to share files like p2p programs out there?

Tags: c#, p2p, share, file-transfer

i am developing an application which requires the distribution of files to several peers. as i understand about p2p is that it downloads chunks of the file from peers who has the same file which makes the download process faster.

my example is:

there is Peer A(which acts as server),Peer B,Peer C and Peer D.

Peer B,C and D will need to update or receive new file at a certain period. so if there's any changes or new files on peer A(server), peer B,C and D will need to retrieve it for update purpose.

so what im picturing here is that p2p should work like this for my situation:

Peer B receives/pulls the files from server A, peer C than will also pull/receives chunk of the files from Peer A AND peer B(like p2p tech like torrent and etc.). same goes with peer D which will pull/receive chunk of the files from peer A,B and C.

so in a sense, it's p2p.

my question is, is there a tech out there that will help me do this kind of file distribution? i was hoping there to ease this networking part.

is there such library out there?

[image: the graphical representation of my application]

Comment: @Dani, i have done my research using google but since this stuff is a bit advance and not clear to me, i was hoping people who knows about this can give a detail explanation. thats why i decided to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29)?

> The BitTorrent protocol can be used to reduce the server and network impact of distributing even large files. Rather than downloading a file from a single source server, the BitTorrent protocol allows users to join a "swarm" of hosts to download and upload from each other simultaneously.

There's a .NET implementation called [MonoTorrent](http://www.monotorrent.com/).